# How to achieve if else statement while querying with database?

Tags: 7, database

I want to export some data from `test_records` table depend upon supplied `from date and to date`. I from and to date not supplied I want to export whole data. So how I can achieve that. Below is my code.

```
$from_date = strtotime($form_state['values']['fromdate']." 00:00:00");
$to_date   = strtotime($form_state['values']['todate']." 23:59:59"); 

$result = db_select('test_records', 'n')
      ->fields('n')
      ->condition('submitted_time',  array($from_date, $to_date), 'BETWEEN')
      ->execute()
      ->fetchAll();
```

I am using one condition that will compare `submitted_time` in database with supplied `from` and `to` dates.  But When I pass nothing, it should get all the data from that table. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can add if statement to a query but as you already have the values of `$form_state['values']['fromdate']` and `$form_state['values']['todate']` you can just add an if statement. If those two don't have values then execute a different query without the `condition('submitted_time',  array($from_date, $to_date), 'BETWEEN')` condition.